# Как в peewee переподключиться к базе данных?

Tags: python, peewee

Везде приводят пример как успешно подключится к базе и инициализировать классы.
А если в последующем произошел дисконнект? Как переподключиться? Что надо написать в main.py, чтоб цикл продолжал работать? (понятно что try, но помимо?..)

файл models.py

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

файл main.py

```
from models import *

While True:
    records = Person.select()

    for i in records:
        print(i.name)
```

Comment: Я очень-очень сильно удивлюсь, если у вас отдисконнектится sqlite

Comment: Ну а вообще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345549